# Django deployment using passenger-wsgi

Tags: python, django, passenger, wsgi, dreamhost

It appeared that I successfully deployed the application using this code

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "UR.settings"
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

However Django did not run properly because it could not get to the latest version of Django and ran an old version with Python 2.3. I installed the latest Django and Python 2.7 and I added those two lines and now I am getting an internal server error..

```
INTERP = '/home/username/opt/python-2.7.7/bin/python'
if sys.executable != INTERP:
        os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
```

I am sure this is the right path to my Python 2.7 ... any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it , 
I was deploying on dreamhost and their servers had django1.2 and python2.6, whenever i tried to make python2.7 and let it be the default passenger gets to python 2.6 and successfully executes python2.7 but for some reason it ran into django1.2 instead of the latest django i installed.

I installed python2.7 in /usr/ (using a sudoer account ofcourse) then i installed the new django into site packages and now I no longer need the lines that execute python2.7 as it is the default now along with django 1.7

I have also edited the passenger-wsgi file and this code worked very fine for me....

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'projectname')) #I needed this
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

The only setback now is that the server is to slow in it's response but other than that everything went fine

And i found a great trick to get into the logs of django

> 1. ssh into your server
> 2. Execute python manage.py runserver
> 3. Open another ssh session at the same time
> 4. In the new ssh execute lynx localhost:8000

Then you will be able to see logs and debug information from django in the second ssh .